# Link file not in the wwwroot directory

Tags: php, windows-server-2008

is it possible to link files in my webserver outside the "wwwroot" directory using php. for example I have a php page and I want to link a file in the music files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you link to them? No

Can you serve the files? Sure!

```
header('Content-Type: '.filetype(OUTSIDE_OF_WEB_ROOT_FILE));
readfile(OUTSIDE_OF_WEB_ROOT_FILE);
exit;
```